# Laravel project code not refelcting changes to view files

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, laravel-5, inertiajs

I created a Laravel (5.1.3) project with breeze as the starter kit. I am planning to use the react as frontend to this project. I run the `php artisan serve` command. The boiler plate template is working but any changes to files `/resources/js/Pages/Welcome.jsx` or `/resources/views/welcome.blade.php` is not reflecting. I have tried:

1. clearing the *storage/framework/views* folder ,
2. run command `php artisan view:clear` ,
3. run command `php artisan config:clear` ,
4. run command `composer dump-autoload` ,

Still no change to the initial view. What am I doing wrong?

And I configured to make react as frontend library so I don't need the `welcome.blade.php` file right?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the javascript side of things. Have you tried running `npm install && npm run dev`?

Comment: Are you sure you're testing the same project you're editing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with :

1. npm install && npm run dev
2. clear browser cache / cookies using CTRL + F5 if u using windows.